# Creating a dataframe in a for loop based on another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame, `df`, and I'd like to get all the columns in it and the count of unique values in it and save it as another data frame. I can't seem to find a way to do that. I **can**, however, *print* what I want on the console. Here's what I mean:

```
def counting_unique_values_in_df(df):
    for evry_colm in df:
        print (evry_colm, "-", df[evry_colm].value_counts().count())
```

Now that prints what I want just fine. Instead of printing, if I do something like `newdf = pd.DataFrame(evry_colm, df[evry_colm].value_counts().count(), columns = ('a', 'b'))`, it throws an error that reads "*TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()*". Obviously, that isn't right.

Soo, how can I make a data frame like `columnName` and `UniqueCounts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
print(df)
print()
df = pd.DataFrame({col: [df[col].nunique()] for col in df})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  3
3  2  4

   A  B
0  2  4
```

Answer (score 1):

To count unique values per column you can use apply and nunique function on data frame.
Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
       {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
       {'a': 2, 'b': 2}
     ])

count_series = df.apply(lambda col: col.nunique())

#   returned object is pandas Series 
#   a    2
#   b    1
#   to map it to DataFrame try

pd.DataFrame(count_series).T
```